# How to express equation with particular word in R markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

all
I'm new to R markdown. I tried several times but still cannot get it.

```
$\beta 0=-1.85846803.$ $\beta 1=0.01977384.$ $\beta 2=1.61866125.$ $D11=0.011109012.$ $\sigma^2=0.004051476 $
```

In this, I wanna print out beta0,beta1,beta2, D11, signa^2 values. how to use LaTex to present this one??

```
$Yij=\beta 0+\beta 1*ageij +\beta 2*heightij+ boi+b1i+eij $
```

Is something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you wanted to write:

```
$Y_{ij}=\beta_0+\beta_1*age_{ij} +\beta_2*height_{ij}+ b_{oi}+b_{1i}+\varepsilon_{ij}$
```

Comment: yep. How about first stat? I wanna list values . Is expreesion  wright?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what your goal is but that seems to work. Slightly modified version: `$\beta_0=-1.85846803$ `
`$\beta_1=0.01977384$ `
`$\beta_2=1.61866125$ `
`$D11=0.011109012$` 
`$\sigma^2=0.004051476$`